# Rails3 Routing Error only in images#destroy - I dont't get why... "no route matches..." - paperclip?

Tags: javascript, seo, pagerank

I have a rails3 application and I am using jquery-rails..
I can delete all the objects of my other models, but not my images.

Maybe an paperclip problem?

images_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed image."
    redirect_to images_url
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :images do
    resources :comments
  end
```

rake routes

```
                 images GET    /images(.:format)                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"images"}
                        POST   /images(.:format)                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"images"}
              new_image GET    /images/new(.:format)                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"images"}
             edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"images"}
                  image GET    /images/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images"}
                        PUT    /images/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"images"}
                        DELETE /images/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"images"}
```

my view file:

```
 <%= link_to "Delete Image", @image, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :destroy %>
```

the error:

```
routing error
No route matches "/images/8"
```

I don't get where is the error here, and why it is only with the images?

Comment: haha, okay I got sometimes help to just write the problem down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has of course to be :method => :delete, not :method => :destroy